# In 32nd iteration FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating scatter diagrams and saving them into files in a loop, and then on the 23 iteration it gives me this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hrdinhal\\Desktop\\OPTIX\\Fines B\\Slike\\Fines B mids and Mids Rush/Drag.png'
```

How can I fix it?

```
def scatter(i):
    while i < (len(df1.columns) - 3):
        xi = df1.iloc[:, i]
        plt.scatter(xi, df1.iloc[:, 1])
        plt.title('Fines B mids and {}'.format(df1.columns[i]))
        plt.ylabel('Fines B mids')
        plt.xlabel(df1.columns[i])
        plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\hrdinhal\\Desktop\\OPTIX\\Fines B\\Slike\\Fines B mids and {}.png'.format(df1.columns[i]))
        i = i+1
        plt.show()
    return 
scatter(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to execute your program using the debugger ?
A step by step execution would have helped.

Most likely, `df1.columns[i]`does not return what you expect to be a valid part of a filename `Fines B mids and Mids Rush/Drag.png`
Python gave you exactly all the intel needed to understand the issue.
Faulty line:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\hrdinhal\\Desktop\\OPTIX\\Fines B\\Slike\\Fines B mids and {}.png'.format(df1.columns[i]))
```

Faulty filename :

```
`Fines B mids and Mids Rush/Drag.png`
```

Comment: No, I haven't, I will try.